# text input change value and instant check

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I am wondering if it is **possible to check the arrays** and **update the results div when the value of a textbox (input field) is changed** without clicking submit.
In my attempt I have tried to use php and jQuery, however to no avail. I want to be able to check the arrays as soon as the user clicks a button and replacing the text in the input field (`$query`). 
Is there any other way I can attempt this?

The code is as follows:

```
<?php 
//arrays
$results = array();
$results["car"] = array( "name" => "toyota");
$results["food"] = array( "name" => "bread");
$results["tool"] = array( "name" => "hammer");
$query = "";
?>
<script>
function colour() {
    document.getElementById("s").value = "colour";
}
function tool() {
    document.getElementById("s").value = "tool";
}
</script>

<div id="form">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $query; ?>" id="s" />
</div>

<button onclick="colour()">Check colours</button>
<button onclick="tool()">Check tools</button>




<div id="result">
<?php  
         foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
           if ($key === $query) {
               echo " match found! for " . $key;
           }
         }
    ?>
</div>
```

**I look forward for your input.** :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you don't want to submit your form, you can do that all in javascript.

First you need to make sure your values from results are passed correctly to the script:

```
<?php 
//arrays
$results = array();
$results["car"] = array( "name" => "toyota");
$results["food"] = array( "name" => "bread");
$results["tool"] = array( "name" => "hammer");
?>
<script>
// Generate a variable / object that contains the necessary information
var results = <?php echo json_encode($results); ?>;

function colour() {
    document.getElementById("s").value = "colour";
}
function tool() {
    document.getElementById("s").value = "tool";
}
</script>
```

Now you will have an object available in your script that you can use to check the values as soon as the button is clicked.

So in your function you could use that

```
function colour() {
    document.getElementById("s").value = "colour";
    // here you can use `results`
    // you would need to add some details / logic to your question
    // if you need more information
}
```

Also note that the default for a `button` element is a submit button, at least in HTML 4 so you should probably cancel the default event if you have a form surrounding your form elements.

You can that in a click handler which will at the same time remove your inline javascript:

```
$('button').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // the rest of your click event handler
});
```

Comment: what i wanted to do was to use the input field as a search box so that whenever the user types info in the box, or clicks the buttons, the result would instantly appear in the results div without the user having to click submit. the reason why i wanted php is because i am more familiar with it over javascript, hence the reason why i wanted to keep javascript to a minimum.

Comment: @user3108623 It would also be very easy to make an ajax request, check the jQuery manual on `$.ajax()`. You would have to separate the php code you want to run in a separate file and call that. And when the results come back, you process them. It's a bit too broad for the information you have given though, it's unclear how the php relates to the form and the javascript. Perhaps you should ask a more detailed question when you run into more specific problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find user's value in the server side array from javascript, try to use ajax queries:

check.php

```
<?php
$results = array();
$results["car"] = array( "name" => "toyota");
$results["food"] = array( "name" => "bread");
$results["tool"] = array( "name" => "hammer");

echo isExists($results) ? "1" : "0";

function isExists($result){
    if (!isset($_GET['query'])) return false;
    $query = $_GET['query'];
    if (!array_key_exist($query, $results)) return false;
    return true;
}
?>
```

add jquery to the head of your page and make an ajax query:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").on("click", function(){
        $.get("check.php?query=" + $("#s").val(), function(result){
           if (result === 1) $("#result").html("found"); else $("#result").html("not found");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you have to realize is that the php code is invoked only once, on your server. It doesn't show on the client-side, so it won't run on the client's browser.

Here's a partial solution using jQuery (since you used this tag...). You issue an ajax request from the client side. The function colour becomes:

```
function colour() {
    $("#s").val("colour"); // set the value, same as document.getElementById
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php&value="+$("#s").val(), 
    }).done(function(data) { // this function will run once the results are loaded
        $("#result").html( data ); // set the content of the result div to be the output of the php script
    });
}
```

The php script "test.php" will read:

```
<?php 
//arrays
$results = array();
$results["car"] = array( "name" => "toyota");
$results["food"] = array( "name" => "bread");
$results["tool"] = array( "name" => "hammer");

$query = $_GET["value"]
foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
  if ($key === $query) {
    echo " match found! for " . $key;
  }
}

?>
```

This solution is very partial and I haven't tested it. I wrote it to give you a sense of how things should go (there might be other solutions).

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're trying to do something that's not possible, which is combining serverside (php) and clientside (js) code. The PHP runs on your server and your js is running in the client browser. So the PHP is already executed before the contents of the page is served to the client, after that the javascript gets executed there.

In your case you should either check with an ajax request to check with PHP if the value is in your arrays, or create json objects so you can check values with JS on the client (if you are ok with showing this data in the source)

PHP check on ajax request (with jquery):

index.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkResults(type)
    {
        $('#s').val(type);

        $.get("check.php?type=" + type, (function( data ) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        });

    } 
</script>

<div id="form">
<input type="text" value="" id="s" />
</div>

<button onclick="colour()">Check colours</button>
<button onclick="tool()">Check tools</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

check.php:

```
<?php 
    //arrays
    $results = array();
    $results["car"] = array( "name" => "toyota");
    $results["food"] = array( "name" => "bread");
    $results["tool"] = array( "name" => "hammer");

    if (isset($_GET['type'] && isset($results[$_GET['type']])) {
        die('Match found for ' . $_GET['type']);
    }

    // nothing found
    die('Not found');
```

Option with json object check in js, generated by php:

index.php:

```
<?php 
    //arrays
    $results = array();
    $results["car"] = array( "name" => "toyota");
    $results["food"] = array( "name" => "bread");
    $results["tool"] = array( "name" => "hammer");
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var results = '<?php echo json_encode($results); ?>';

    function checkResults(type)
    {
        $('#s').val(type);

        var $result = $('#result');
        $result.empty();
        for (var key in results) {
            if (results.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                $result.append('Found match for key' + key + '<br>');
            }
        }
    } 
</script>

<div id="form">
<input type="text" value="" id="s" />
</div>

<button onclick="checkResults('colour')">Check colours</button>
<button onclick="checkResults('tool')">Check tools</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

I did not check any of the code, but it will give you a general idea.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i understand your needs correctly, but I have two suggestions for you:

1. If you want to write some functions and handle them by your way - i suggest using angular js.
2. If you want something like autocomplete - you can use something like 
   [Typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/).

Edit:
Here is an angular js similar problem i think. You can view source of it and analize how it is done
[Angular example](http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-4/app/)

It would help you if you pass standard tutorial of Angular JS just to understand the basics.

Edit2: Here is how you can load json data by ajax. 
[Load json by ajax](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/consuming-external-services/requesting-json-data-with-ajax.html).
So in general - you can request some url (instead of json file on server) and get data from server. In your case - you will have to serve some json data from php - and angular js will parse it and you will have your set of data.
you can ofcourse also load data from json file and have some cron action to update the file - it all depends of your needs.

Comment: hi @pietr, after having a look at angularjs, i think you understood my needs correctly. can you show me just for reference how the above foreach would look like to check whether the input , matches what is in the php array, using angularjs.

Comment: I can give you very simillar example to analize - i hope it will help you find a right solution.

Comment: thanks for showing me an example. the thing i am trying to achieve is to have the arrays in php and gather from there using a combination of php + angularjs. in your example the data is gathered from the js controller, i am wondering if it is possible to gather those values from php arrays instead?

Comment: yes - You have to load for example json to js by ajax. I`ll edited post

Comment: question is will the arrays be visible like when using js or will they be not invisible like in php?

Comment: I`m not sure i follow your question. You will pass arrays from php as a echo jsonEncode($returnArray) on the requested url. Then, in js, you will have a json object wchich you can process.

Comment: btw - isn't the "visible" and "not invisible" the same meaning? :)

Comment: sorry meant visible on the last part of the question. ;) the json object will have all arrays from the php and they will be visible from the source code right? or would i be better off using a database such as mongodb to "hide" those arrays from view and still be able to use?

Comment: When you will send request to server - you can get only those array what matches your filters. So from source code will be only wisible that what you send to view